# jQuery does not send Cookie to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, cors

Cross-domain problem. From HTTP to same domain HTTPS.

Server requires `X-Requested-With` header so I set it in jQuery ajax options:

```
'headers': {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
```

jQuery sends OPTION then:

```
OPTIONS /my/test/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.my.dev
Origin: http://www.my.dev
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with
```

Server responds:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Then jQuery sends "actual" request:

```
POST /my/test/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.test.dev
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Origin: http://www.test.dev
```

**Cookie header is missing!**

Server responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: application/json
Set-Cookie: SESSID=3tg8svt3lrv97v155uv2kqr3o2; expires=Sat, 25-Apr-2015 17:35:13 GMT; Max-Age=259200; path=/
```

Adding

```
    'xhrFields': {
        'withCredentials': true
    },
    'crossDomain': {
        'crossDomain': true
    },
```

to jQuery ajax options results in jQuery not sending actual request at all, only OPTIONS.

How to send cookie?
Could at least someone confirm that cookies are sent in similar setup?

Comment: was the cookie defined as https only? There's nothing you can do to override that...

Comment: Are you sure the cookie isn't an HTTPS-only cookie?

Comment: Updated question with server response to actual request. Cookie is not HTTPS only as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

Made it work.

Some important notes:

- `crossDomain` does not seem to do anything
- if you have `withCredentials` in ajax options but do not have `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` in `OPTIONS` response then actual request is not made
- if you do not have `withCredentials` jQuery does not send `Cookie` header
- if you do not send `Cookie` in actual request then server does not send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` headers back
- response to actual request **must** have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` headers - otherwise jQuery does not parse response body (though it sees response code and all headers alright) and throws an error to console
- having cookie domain not set does not change anything
- headers letter case does not matter though jQuery lowercases forced header name

PS

- I'm not sure but I guess jQuery does not add anything extra special here so jQuery = browser
- server: nginx 1.7.6, PHP 5.5.24; browsers: FF31, Chrome42; jquery 2.0.3

Comment: I have withCredentials but the PUT/OPTIONS is not sending cookie (GET/POST do send cookie). Any reason why this would be true?